# ELF: Dump paths to .so files imported by binary

Tags: shared-library, elf

I am trying to dump the full paths of the shared libraries that are imported by an ELF file (`/usr/bin/ls`)

Using `readelf --dyn-syms /usr/bin/ls`  I get the name of the libraries, but not where they are located on the filesystem:

```
101: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND [...]@LIBSELINUX_1.0 (4)
```

Using `objdump -T /usr/bin/ls` I get even more information (including function names):

```
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000 (LIBSELINUX_1.0) getfilecon
```

This is useful information, but how can I extract the location of the library on disk?
I could run the file and see what it opens via `lsof`, but is there any way to do this without running the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what `ldd` is for:

```
$ ldd /bin/ls
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd67705000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f25aaab6000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f25aa8f1000)
    libpcre2-8.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007f25aa859000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f25aa853000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f25aab52000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f25aa831000)
```

This is liable to include more than the libraries shown by `readelf`, since it will process transitive dependencies as well.